# BST implementation for insert (put) and contain (search) in Python

Tags: python, binary-search

I was asked about this question by my friend, so I decided to implement it recursively. I would like to get some code review.

```
#         Create a BinarySearchTree class
#
#             The BinarySearchTree class should contain the following
#             properties:
#
#                    root:   {Node} (initially root Node)
#
#             The BinarySearchTree class should also contain the following
#             methods:
#
#                  put:   A method that takes takes an integer value, and
#                            creates a node with the given input.  The method
#                            will then find the correct place to add the new
#                            node. Values larger than the current node node go
#                            to the right, and smaller values go to the left.
#
#                            Input:     value {Integer}
#                            Output:    {None}
#
#                  contain:   A method that searches if a value exists with a
#                            exists within the tree and returns true if found.
#
#                            Input:     value {Integer}
#                            Output:    {Boolean}
#


import unittest
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class BinarySearchTree():
    def __init__(self):
        #self.root = None
        self.root = Node()
        self.size = 0

    def put(self, value):
        self._put(value, self.root)

    def _put(self, value, node):
        if node.value is None:
            node.value = value
        else:
            if value < node.value:
                if node.left is None:
                    node.left = Node()
                self._put(value, node.left)
            else:
                if node.right is None:
                    node.right = Node()
                self._put(value, node.right)


    def contains(self, value):
        return self._contains(value, self.root)

    def _contains(self, value, node):
        if node is None or node.value is None:
            return False
        else:
            if value == node.value:
                return True
            elif value < node.value:
                return self._contains(value, node.left)
            else:
                return self._contains(value, node.right)

    def in_order_traversal(self):
        acc = list()
        self._in_order_traversal(self.root, acc)
        return acc

    def _in_order_traversal(self, node, acc):
        if node is None or node.value is None:
            return
        self._in_order_traversal(node.left, acc)
        acc.append(node.value)
        self._in_order_traversal(node.right, acc)
```

I also added 5 unit tests, and they all pass:

```
import unittest

class TestBST(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.search_tree = BinarySearchTree()

    def test_bst(self):
        self.search_tree.put(3)
        self.search_tree.put(1)
        self.search_tree.put(2)
        self.search_tree.put(5)
        self.assertFalse(self.search_tree.contains(0))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(1))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(2))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(3))
        self.assertFalse(self.search_tree.contains(4))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(5))
        self.assertFalse(self.search_tree.contains(6))

        self.assertEqual(self.search_tree.in_order_traversal(), [1, 2, 3, 5])

    def test_empty(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.search_tree.in_order_traversal(), [])

    def test_negative(self):
        self.search_tree.put(-1)
        self.search_tree.put(11)
        self.search_tree.put(-10)
        self.search_tree.put(50)
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(-1))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(11))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(-10))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(50))

        self.assertEqual(self.search_tree.in_order_traversal(), [-10, -1, 11, 50])

    def test_dupes(self):
        self.search_tree.put(1)
        self.search_tree.put(2)
        self.search_tree.put(1)
        self.search_tree.put(2)
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(1))
        self.assertTrue(self.search_tree.contains(2))

        self.assertEqual(self.search_tree.in_order_traversal(), [1, 1, 2, 2])

    def test_none(self):
        self.search_tree.put(None)
        self.assertFalse(self.search_tree.contains(None))

        self.assertEqual(self.search_tree.in_order_traversal(), [])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I think is the main drawback of your design.  You can think of a tree as being either:

1. An (empty) leaf
2. A node containing a value and having left and right branches which are themselves trees

It would be nice if these two possibilities were clearly modelled in your code.  However, you've used two ways of representing a leaf, either as `None` (e.g., when `node.right == None`, that means that `node` has a leaf on its right branch) or as a node with **value** `None` (e.g., when you create a new, empty tree, it's just a leaf, but you represent it as a `Node` with `value == None`).

I know you thought about this issue already, since you have a `#self.root = None` line commented out in your source.

As a result, throughout your code, you've got a lot of mostly redundant checks like:

```
if node is None or node.value is None:
    ...
```

where the `node.value is None` part is really only an issue at the root (since the tree should otherwise have no nodes with value `None`, unless you've `put` a `None` in your tree).

It also leads to some weird behavior:

```
> t = BinarySearchTree()
> t.put(None)
> t.put(None)
> t.put(3)
> t.put(None)
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()
>
```

You could argue that the type error makes sense, but why wasn't it thrown when we put `3` in the tree?

Anyway, a side effect of this design choice is that you've had to move all of the logic into the `BinarySearchTree` object, and the `Node` object is just a method-less data container.  That's because, given a "node", you never know whether it's (1) a `None`; (2) a `Node` that contains a valid value or; (3) a `Node` that contains a `None`.  You need to handle cases (1) and (3) with similar logic, so it's pointless to put the logic for case (3) in the `Node` (because you need to do the same thing in case (1) where you don't **have** a `Node`).  Therefore, logic for cases (1) and (3) has to go in the `BinarySearchTree`, and when you've gotten that far, you might as well stick logic for case (2) in there, too.

Try the following exercise.  Create two objects, one to represent `Node`s that contain values, and one to represent `Leaf`s that don't:

```
class Leaf:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = Leaf()
        self.right = Leaf()
```

Now, create a `Tree` object that dispatches to its `self.root` -- this root will initially be a `Leaf` when the tree is empty, but will change to a `Node` when we put something in the tree.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Leaf()

    def put(self, value):
        if value is not None:
            self.root = self.root.put(value)

    def contains(self, value):
        return self.root.contains(value)

    def in_order_traversal(self):
        return self.root.in_order_traversal()
```

Now, see if you can implement your tree by *only* adding `put`, `contains`, and `in_order_traversal` methods to the `Leaf` and `Node` objects, and see how that design works.

Note that you should maintain two invariants on `Node`s:

1. `node.value` is always a valid value (never a `None`)
2. `node.left` and `node.right` are always either `Leaf`s or `Node`s (never a `None`)

**SPOILERS...**

Here was my solution.  It passes your test, and I think it represents a cleaner design.  Instead of differentiating between leafs and nodes using conditional statements in the `Tree` object, that decision is made by dispatching to either a `Node` or `Leaf` class.  The downside is that it splits up the logic for a particular operation into two functions in different classes (so to "understand" `put`, you need to look at the implementations in both the `Leaf` and `Node` classes), but that's a pretty typically issue in object-oriented designs, so people are used to it.

```
class Leaf:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def put(self, value):
        return Node(value)

    def contains(self, value):
        return False

    def in_order_traversal(self):
        return []

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = Leaf()
        self.right = Leaf()

    def put(self, value):
        if value < self.value:
            self.left = self.left.put(value)
        else:
            self.right = self.right.put(value)
        return self

    def contains(self, value):
        if value < self.value:
            return self.left.contains(value)
        elif value > self.value:
            return self.right.contains(value)
        else:
            return True

    def in_order_traversal(self):
        return self.left.in_order_traversal() \
            + [self.value] + self.right.in_order_traversal()

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Leaf()

    def put(self, value):
        if value is not None:
            self.root = self.root.put(value)

    def contains(self, value):
        return self.root.contains(value)

    def in_order_traversal(self):
        return self.root.in_order_traversal()
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why go with a Tree, Node, and Leaf rather than Tree and EmptyTree? The Tree class you've proposed is a light wrapper around the root node.

Comment: Yes, except the root node can change, from a `Leaf` to a `Node`, so it's a light wrapper around an object that changes between creation and the first successful `put` operation.  Now, because Python allows you to perform tricks like changing the class of an object, we could set things up so that `t = EmptyTree()` creates an `EmptyTree` and then `t.put(10)` changes `t` to a `Tree` with `self.__class__ = Tree`.  I find that a little ugly, but it works okay, and some people might prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

appending to @K. A. Buhr's answer,
just for your tests, manual additions looks a bit out. try a loop

from

```
    self.search_tree.put(3)
    self.search_tree.put(1)
    self.search_tree.put(2)
    self.search_tree.put(5)
```

to

```
    for num in [3, 1, 2, 5]:
        self.search_tree.put(num)
```

which saves some lines, improving code redability !